# add multiple webservices on same server and port

Tags: centos, load-balancing, apache2

What I have this on a testing enviroment

server01.domanin:**8080/urlofws?wsdl**

server02.domanin:**8080/urlofotherws?wsdl**

the two webservices should be able to use via loadbalancer

thesite.domain:/urlofws?wsdl 
or
thesite.domain:/urlofotherws?wsdl

this is what I have done

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80>
        ServerName thesite.domain
        ServerAlias thesite

        RedirectMatch ^/$ server01.domanin:**8080/urlofws?wsdl**

        JkMount /* onejkmount

        <Location />
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        ErrorLog    /var/log/httpd/error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

I know this is not usefull to have multiple webserservices and on multiple servers.. ¿Where can I see some examples to understand this?

Comment: You want to proxy, not redirect

Comment: I know but I don't know to to accomplish that... can you show me a link with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

As @jordanm says, use Proxy, take a look at the [Apache's Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

Simply, inside your `VirtualHost`, do something like this:

```
ProxyPass "/urlofws"  "http://server01.domainin:8080/urlofws"
ProxyPassReverse "/urlofws"  "http://server01.domainin:8080/urlofws"
ProxyPass "/urlofotherws"  "http://server01.domainin:8080/urlofotherws"
ProxyPassReverse "/urlofotherws"  "http://server01.domainin:8080/urlofotherws"
```

I wouldn't add this as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.